# How do I register a custom Doctrine Repository in the container as a service? (Framework agnostic)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, containers

N.B I'm **not** using the Symfony framework. I'm using the symfony container component along with `Doctrine ORM`. I've created a custom repo and want to register it as a service. I'm not using any framework.

```
class FooRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    //...
}
```

Here's what I'm messing around with in the container:

```
<services>
    <!--<service id="doctrine" class="Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory" />-->
    <!--<service id="entity_manager" class="Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager"/>-->


    <service id="doctrine" class="Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager"/>
    <service id="app.org_1_repository" class="Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository">
        <factory service="doctrine" method="getRepository"/>
        <argument type="string">Foo\Bar\Entity\MyEntity</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

> Error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Access to non-public constructor of class Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'.

The error makes sense. I think I was closer with the (now commented) `DefaultRepositoryFactory` approach but couldn't get that to work either.

Solving this problem is not very clear having researched a lot. 99% of the answers are related to Symfony.

Comment: The issue is not the repository but rather your definition of the entity manager service.  It takes a bit of effort to create an entity manager: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#obtaining-an-entitymanager You will have to figure out how to convert the necessary configuration to service definitions.  The Symfony framework cheats a bit uses some code in a compiler pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by defining the entity manager in the container like so:

```
<service id="doctrine.xml_configuration">
    <factory class="Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup" method="createXMLMetadataConfiguration" />
    <argument id="doctrine.xml_config_path" type="collection">
        <argument>path/to/mappings</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument id="is_dev_mode">dev_mode</argument>
</service>

<service id="doctrine.em">
    <factory class="Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" method="create"/>
    <argument type="collection">
        <argument key="driver">your_driver</argument>
        <argument key="host">your_host</argument>
        <argument key="dbname">your_db</argument>
        <argument key="user">your_user</argument>
        <argument key="password" type="string">your_password</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine.xml_configuration"/>
</service>
```

Now I can use the entity manager as needed.